# LESS syntax double dashes and parenthesis

Tags: less

The company I work at is using LESS and I'm trying to understand a particular selector method being used and hoping someone can explain the use of dashes and parenthesis in this example:

```
.style--heading-1(){
//properties
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the example you provide, it is not 100% certain, but I'm pretty confident your company is using a specific naming convention called [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/) or maybe a derivate. Like other frameworks (e.g. like OOCSS) it simply helps with organizing big CSS projects. However, according to strict BEM, `.style--heading-1` doesn't seem like particularly good naming... ;)

The `()` are just indicating a parameterless mixin (function) in LESS.

Why don't you just as a coworker to give you more information? There is no shame in being willing to learn.

Comment: Thanks, I think thatwas what I needed. LESS BEM came up with some good search results. Unfortunately the knowledge left with past devs.